# VBScript - Increasing a variable's value

Tags: vbscript

I have the following:

```
firstDate = InputBox("Insert the first report's date desired to obtain", "Report Information - Start", "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

So the user inserts the date, lets say: 2015-04-17

I am trying to find a way by which I can increase the date's value for a specific position (day->DD), for example:

```
dateIncrease = Mid(firstDate, 9, 2)+1
```

I am expecting the above to return 18 (17+1)

How can I increase the value of the date? Please help. Let me know if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was not helpful with what you were asking (I sort of misunderstood your question). I believe joehanna has the answer to what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
firstDate  = "2015-04-17"
dateIncrease = DatePart("d", DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(firstDate )))
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on from [@Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097347/uri-goren), you can also use these statements to increment any part of the date

```
Dim firstDate As String
Dim dateIncrease As Integer

firstDate = "2015-04-17"

'Increment the day part
dateIncrease = DatePart("d", DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(firstDate)))

'Increment the month part
dateIncrease = DatePart("m", DateAdd("m", 1, DateValue(firstDate)))

'Increment the year part
dateIncrease = DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("yyyy", 1, DateValue(firstDate)))
```

Comment: Can you please explain in what does the DatePart consists? Thanks

Comment: The `DatePart` functions gets a date, and a representation of it's components ("d" for day,"m" for month, "y" for year) and returns one component of it